# What is the meaning of the angular frequency of a spring?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, frequency, spring, oscillators

In this differential equation,

$$ \ddot{x} + \frac{k}{m}x = 0 $$

We assume that

$$ \frac{k}{m} = w^{2}$$

Why is that? And how one can prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don’t *assume* $\omega^2=k/m$: this follows from the solution.

The differential equation you have can be written as
$$
\ddot{x}=-\frac{k}{m}x\, . \tag{1}
$$
Now, what functions have the property that their 2nd derivative is a negative multiple of the original function, as in (1)?  The trig functions have this property to try $x(t)=A\cos(\omega t)+ B\sin(\omega t)$ to find $\ddot{x}=-\omega^2 x$ so that $\omega^2=k/m$ follows by comparison with (1).

Answer (score 2):

The solution of your differential equation is:

$$x(t)=A\,\sin\left(\sqrt {\frac{k}{m}}\,t+\varphi\right)$$

just for convenience we defined

$$\omega:=\sqrt {\frac{k}{m}}\quad  \text{unit}\quad  \frac{1}{\text{s}}$$

and name it "angular frequency"

with:

$$\omega=2\,\pi\,f$$

you get the frequency $f\quad $ ( Unit [Hz]) of your sine wave which dependence on the mass $m$ and the spring constant $k$.

thus :

$$x(t)=A\,\sin\left(2\,\pi\,f\,t+\varphi\right)$$

and your ODE is :

$$\ddot{x}+\omega^2\,x=0$$

Answer (score 0):

For a spring, you have $F=-kx\Rightarrow a=-\frac{k}{m}x\Rightarrow \ddot{x}+\frac{k}{m}x=0$. Now, the spring performs sinusiodal motion, with e.g. amplitude $A$, so $x(t)=A\cos \omega t\Rightarrow a(t)=-A\omega^2\cos \omega t = -\omega ^2 x\Rightarrow \ddot{x}+\omega ^2x=0$. This yields $\frac{k}{m}=\omega^2$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but this solution is only true because you assumed that w is equal to k/m. You're just doing it backwards

Comment: w = sqrt(k/m) *

Comment: If you think about it, I do not assume it anywhere. I only assume $F=-kx$ and $x=A\cos \omega t$. In the last equation, $\omega$ emerges from its definition.

Comment: I said that because if you just solve the differential equation,  sqrt(k/m) appears naturally

Comment: And not w^2, as usual

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about what you mean. $\omega^2$ also comes naturally